# Как прочитать огромный тест из Clipboard в WinForms?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, clipboard

Приложение на WinForms следит за буфером обмена (`Clipboard`), отслеживает наличие данных в формате `HTML Format`. Эти данные можно получать в виде `string`, используя код:

```
string html = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Html)
```

У нужных данных присутствует атрибут-маркер, по которому определяется, что данные подлежат обработке.

Всё хорошо работает, пока пользователь не копирует большой HTML.
Например, этого можно добиться, если в Excel заполнить таблицу размером *50000х10* и скопировать её. В этом случае `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText` отрабатывает *~20* секунд. Что очень чувствительно для пользователя.

По сути, для идентификации своих данных загружать весь текст html не нужно, достаточно найти атрибут в первом элементе.

Можно ли прочитать текст из Clipboard частично? Например, для `HTML Format` получить Stream и считать только необходимое количество байт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема данного сценария заключается в том, что в функционале Clipboard есть возможность сделать отсроченную загрузку данных, см. [Delayed Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649014(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Delayed_Rendering). Т.е., если мы получаем уведомление о том, что состояние Clipboard изменилось, то это ещё не значит, что данные были полностью загружены в Clipboard. Они загружаются туда, когда мы их запрашиваем, например, при помощи `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText`.

Так вот, в выше описанном сценарии, когда мы вызываем функцию `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText`, то после этого процесс Excel начинает формировать данные для Clipboard и нам приходиться ждать, когда он закончит это делать. К сожалению, повлиять на это никак нельзя.